# Block all countries except 1 country, but whitelist a URL from this block

Tags: .htaccess, security, geolocation

To reduce spam, my website has the following in `.htaccess`:

```
GeoIPEnable On
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AU AllowCountry
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
```

However, Facebook now complains it can't access my site's privacy policy page `https://www.example.com/privacy.php` - it receives a 403.

Facebook needs access to this page to keep the login with Facebook feature compliant with privacy laws.

How do I whitelist this URL from the GEO block above, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whitelist that particular URL you could just set the `AllowCountry` env var when that URL is requested. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/privacy\.php$" AllowCountry
```

*Aside:* Although why does FB need to access your "privacy policy page"? And why is it seemingly only complaining about that one URL?

Comment: Beaut, thank you, that resolved it. Facebook needs access to this page to keep the login with Facebook feature compliant with privacy laws.